# Como posso converter snake_case para camelCase (e vice-versa) em Python?

Tags: python, string, camel-case

Como eu poderia, de maneira mais `pythonic` possível, converter uma string `snake_case` para `camelCase` ?

Exemplo:

```
  snake1 = 'minha_string_snake_case' # minhaStringSnakeCase
  snake2 = '_teste_string' #  _TestString
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma versão mais simples seria utilizar expressão regular desde o início. No módulo `re` existe a função `sub()` que permite fazer substituições dentro de uma string utilizando expressão regulares.

Mais do que isso, `re.sub()` te permite passar uma função para processar o padrão encontrado e retornar uma string para a substituição, o que se encaixa muito bem no seu caso.

Logo:

```
>>> import re
```

**Para camelCase:**

```
>>> camel = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]_([a-zA-Z])',
...                lambda _ : _.group(0)[0] + _.group(1).upper(),
...                '_para_camel_case')
>>> camel
'_paraCamelCase'
```

**Para snake_case:**

```
>>> snake = re.sub('[A-Z]',
...                lambda _ : '_' +  _.group(0).lower(),
...                '_paraSnakeCase')
>>> snake
'_para_snake_case'
```

Possivelmente haverá expressões regulares mais adequadas, mas aí fica para você.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer é trabalhando com [`list comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) e [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), como no exemplo abaixo:

```
import itertools

def flatten(lista):
    return list(itertools.chain(*lista))

def converte_para_camel_string(valor):
    valor = valor.split('_')
    if valor[0] == '':
        valor[0] = '_'
    ret = [valor[0]]
    ret.append([x.capitalize() for x in valor[1:]])
    ret = flatten(ret)
    return ''.join(ret)
```

e você terá o seguinte resultado:

```
snake1 = converte_para_camel_string('minha_string_snake_case') # minhaStringSnakeCase
snake2 = converte_para_camel_string('_teste_string') #  _TestString
```

Já para converter do camel case para snake, você pode usar [expressões regulares](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) da seguinte forma:

```
import re

def converte_para_snake_string(valor):
    valor = re.findall('[A-Z]*[^A-Z]*', valor) # dá um split nas letras maiúsculas
    if valor[0] == '_':
        valor[0] = ''
    valor = [x.lower() for x in valor]
    return '_'.join(valor)[:-1]
```

Isso retornará:

```
string1 = converte_para_snake_string('testeString') #teste_string
string2 = converte_para_snake_string('_TesteString') #_teste_string
```

Comment: o que `itertools.chain(*lista)` faz exatamente, @FelipeAvelar?

Comment: Ele pega cada elemento da lista, porque o que acontece é que ele retorna uma lista dentro de uma lista e, pra dar o `join`, eu preciso que ele seja só uma lista de strings. Por isso eu torno a lista linear (flatten)

Comment: O `_` antes é o seguinte: Algumas linguagens, como PHP, usam declarações de métodos protegidos ou privado com o `_`. Esse é o único motido de eu querê-lo lá!

Comment: Vai ser bom, vou fazer um plugin para o Sublime Text :)

Comment: Em Python, um `_` antes é protegido por convenção. Privado é implementado pela própria linguagem com `__`, como pode ser visto [nessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/797814/1606920)

Comment: Curiosidade: Há algum problema em usar a função `map`? algo parecido com  `''.join(map('minha_string'.split('_'), lambda x: x.capitalize()))`?

Comment: Eu não testei, mas eu imagino que isso dê problema quando começar com `_` e ele sempre dará _ upcase_  na primeira letra...

Comment: Isso definitivamente não é pythonico.

Answer (score 1):

Para converter para CamelCase, simplesmente quebre a string nas "_" e capitalize a primeira letra - e  isso pode ser feito numa única expressão razoavelmente legível (sem a necessidade de declarar função, ou de métodos do itertools):

```
CamelCase = "".join(word.capitalize() for word in snake_case.split("_"))
```

Se precisar que a primeira letra seja minúscula, você pode ou seguir a expressão acima com um simples e legível `CamelCase = CamelCase[0].lower() + CamerlCase[1:]`, u colocar um contador e um if inine na primeira expressão para não capitalizar a primeira palavra:

```
CamelCase = "".join((word.capitalize() if i else word)for i, word in enumerate(snake_case.split("_")))
```

Para voltar, é necessário processar letra a letra, mas também pode ser feito numa única expressão:

```
 snake_case = "".join(("_" + letter.lower()) if letter.isupper() else letter for letter in CamelCase).strip("_")
```